# Can't get to fix the headers already sent issue with using cookies while developing a WordPress Plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to write a plugin for to register a widget form for some special purpose in order to pay the due payments in CiviCRM but I can't get to work the cookies in the plugin code.As I can see that my cookies are placed before the plugin form html code but still I am getting header already sent error so I am wondering how to fix it?

So I will be grateful if anyone can please help me out with this issue.

Here is my full Plugin Code :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CiviCRM Contribution Later Payment
Plugin URI: http://www.stackoverflow.com/cv/nicefellow1234
Description: This plugin helps in paying due contribution payments through a web form by entering Contribution ID.
Author: Umair Shah Yousafzai
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.huntedhunter.com/mycv/
*/

function my_plugin_activate()
{
    // DO your activation task.

     /* $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_title' => 'Contribution Later Payment Page',
                    'post_content' => 'Pay Your Contribution Payment Now.'
                ) );


    if ($post_id) 
    {
    error_log("New Page Added.");
    } */

}

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,"my_plugin_activate");


    function cl_pay() {


        if ($_POST) {


        if ($_POST['cl_check_email']) {

            $contact_email = $_POST["contact_email"];

            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE sort_name = %s", $contact_email);
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            $count = count($results);
            $contact_id = $results[0]->id;

            if (!$count > 0 ) {

                $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_email WHERE email = %s", $contact_email);
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
                $count = count($results);
                $contact_id = $results[0]->contact_id;
            }       

        }

        if ($_POST['cl_check_phone']) {

            $contact_phone = $_POST["contact_phone"];

            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_phone WHERE phone = %s", $contact_phone);
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            $count = count($results);
            $contact_id = $results[0]->contact_id;

        }

        if ($_POST['cl_check_full_name']) {

            $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
            $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];

            $full_name = $first_name." ".$last_name;

            global $wpdb;
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE display_name = %s", $full_name);
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            $count = count($results);
            $contact_id = $results[0]->id;

            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($results);
            //echo "</pre>";

        }

        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE contact_id = %s", $contact_id);
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        $count = count($results);
        $amount = $results[0]->total_amount;


        if ($count > 0) {
            setcookie("display_check", "none", time()+5);
        }

        if (isset($amount)) { setcookie("display_amount", "block", time()+5); }

        }

        ?>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#choice').change(function () {
      if ( this.value === 'option_1' ) {
          $("#option_1").show("slow");
          $("#option_2").hide("slow");
          $("#option_3").hide("slow");
      }
      else if ( this.value === 'option_2' ) {
        $("#option_2").show("slow");
        $("#option_1").hide("slow");
        $("#option_3").hide("slow");
      }
        else if ( this.value === 'option_3' ) {
            $("#option_3").show("slow");
            $("#option_1").hide("slow");
            $("#option_2").hide("slow");
      } else if ( this.value === 'not_specified' ) {
        $("#option_1").hide("slow");
        $("#option_2").hide("slow");
        $("#option_3").hide("slow");
      }
   });
});


</script>


<style>

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
        url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, 
pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;}

fieldset, img {border:0}

ol, ul, li {list-style:none}

:focus {outline:none}

body,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
h1.testboxh1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

html{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testbox {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 455px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  background-color: #ebebeb; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
}

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

form{
  margin: 0 30px;
text-align:center;
}

label.radio {
    cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 35px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label.radio:before {
  background: #3a57af;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

label.radio:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.30em;
    background: transparent;
    top: 7.5px;
    left: 4.5px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

hr{
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

input[type=text],input[type=password],select {
text-align:center;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 39px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 13px; 
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=password]{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#icon {
  width: 30px;
height:20px;
  background-color: #3a57af;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 0px #cbc9c9;
}

.gender {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.accounttype{
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input.button {
text-align:center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
padding : 8px 30px 8px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: #3a57af; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; 


}

input.button:hover {
  top: 3px;
  background-color:#2e458b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none; 
  box-shadow: none;

}


</style>

</br></br></br></br>
<div class="testbox">
  <h1 class="testboxh1">Pay Due Contribution Pay</h1>

<div class="pay_check" style="display:<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['display_check'])) {echo "block";} else {echo $_COOKIE['display_check']; }?>;">
  <form action="" method="post" >
      <hr>
    <!---<div class="accounttype">
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioOne" name="account" checked/>
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio" chec>Personal</label>
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioTwo" name="account" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Company</label>
    </div> --->
    <center><h3>::Search By::</h3></center>
      <select name="choice" id="choice">
       </br>
    <option value="not_specified">Not Specified</option>
  <option value="option_1">Contact Email</option>
  <option value="option_2">Contact Phone</option>
  <option value="option_3">Full Name</option>
  </select>
    <div id="option_1" style="display:none;">
     <hr>
    <center><h3 style="padding-top: 10px;">::Enter Contact Email::</h3></center>
     <form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="contact_email" placeholder="Contact Email" style="width:250px;"></br>
     </br> <input type="submit" name="cl_check_email" class="button" value="Check">
     </form>
     </br><hr>
    </div>
    <div id="option_2" style="display:none;">
     <hr>
    <center><h3 style="padding-top: 10px;">::Enter Contact Phone No::</h3></center>
     <form action="" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="contact_phone" placeholder="Contact Phone No" style="width:250px;"> </br>
 </br> <input type="submit" name="cl_check_phone" class="button" value="Check">
     </form>
     </br><hr>
    </div>
      <div id="option_3" style="display:none;">
      <hr>
       <form action="" method="post" >
    <center><h3 style="padding-top: 10px;">::Enter Full Name::</h3></center>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"></br>
     </br> <input type="submit" name="cl_check_full_name" class="button" value="Check">
     </form>
     </br><hr>
    </div>

    </br>

<!-- <label id="icon" for="cl_id"><i class="fa fa-tag "  style="padding-right: 13px;"></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="cl_id" id="cl_id" placeholder="Contribution ID" required/></br> -->

</br></br>

</div>

<div class="cl_pay" style="display:<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['display_amount'])) {echo "none";} else {echo $_COOKIE['display_amount']; }?>;">
  <form action="" method="post" >
      <hr>
  <label id="icon" for="cl_pay" style="border-radius:4px;padding-right: 100px;padding-left: 100px;background-color:#422252;"><i class="fa fa-usd " style="">
   <strong><?php echo $amount; ?></strong></i></label>
</br>
    <hr> <input type="submit" name="cl_pay" class="button" value="Pay">
</br></br>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

        <?php 



    }

add_shortcode("cl-pay", "cl_pay");



function my_plugin_deactivate()
{
    // DO your activation task.
    error_log("My Plugin Got Deactivated.");
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,"my_plugin_deactivate");

?>
```

The Error which I am getting is :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm_development\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php:180) in D:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm_development\wp-content\plugins\civicrm_later_contribution_pay.php on line 97

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm_development\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php:180) in D:\xampp\htdocs\civicrm_development\wp-content\plugins\civicrm_later_contribution_pay.php on line 100
```

Besides on Line 97 & 100 I have following code :

97 :

```
if ($count > 0) {
            setcookie("display_check", "none", time()+5);
}
```

100 :

```
if (isset($amount)) { setcookie("display_amount", "block", time()+5); }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same thing when I was working with my new PHP Server. You need to do two things to tackle this issue.

1. Never ever allow any HTML to escape before the headers are sent. (Very Tough)
2. Turn on Output Buffering. (Best and Easy way)

To turn on **Output Buffering**, you need to set in your `php.ini`:

```
output_buffering On
```

Or in your program:

```
ini_set("output_buffering", 1); // OR
ob_start();
```

Comment: @Paveen Kumar : But where do I put it in my code...I am still getting the same error..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Put it at the top of your code. `:)` The plugin file. Put only `ob_start();` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Besides my `output_buffering` value was set to 4096.What does that really mean??

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai I am not sure about that buddy. `:)` Which value?